# How to Mole System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo for a wcf client?

Tags: moles

I am able to Mole `WebRequest.CreateUri` so that I can replace the hostname of the request with another.  However, I would like to Mole `Dns.GetAddrInfo` instead so that I can keep the hostname the same, but make it so that the hostname resolves to another IP address.

In this way, I do not have to edit my hosts file for example as this is a less flexible approach.

Any advice?

Thank you.

**Edit**
I've uploaded a sample Visual Studio 2010 sln to the problem [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42317133/MoleHostAddress.zip):

When opening the sln,

1. Click on the "Create Virtual Directory" button in the Service project properties' Web tab.
2. Rebuild the solution
3. Add the following entry to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`:
   `127.0.0.1 www.productionserver.com`
4. Run the `TestMethod1` unit test in the `Tests` project.
   The unit tests should succeed.
5. Remove the entry from the `hosts` file and re-run the unit test.
   It should fail.

I have looked at the implementation of `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` using a decompiler and noticed that it eventually calls `System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo` to resolve the hostname to an IP address.

I am hoping this sln is simple enough to update and send back (or just comment what needs to be done and\or changed) so I can simply see what is required to solve the problem.

Thank you.

**Edit 2**
It seems this is not currently possible with Moles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Net stack generally can not be moled, as much of he functionality are outside the control of the managed code.

Instead, create an interface and stub in your production code.  Use the interface with dependency injection, to pass the stub to the target code.  This stub simply calls the System.Net methods you wish to intercept, during testing.

Moles will automatically generate a Stub type, from the interface.  Simply instantiate the stub type, detour the desired methods/properties/events of the stub, and then pass the Stub type to the method being tested.

Using stubs and dependency injection works wherever Mole types can not be created.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Mike.  I am still new to Moles so it might take me some time to try and implement this solution (and mark this as the answer).  I am wondering if there is a sample solution (complete with code in the separated projects, ie. test and production) you can point me to that does something similar that can help me better understand and implement a solution to my problem, as I have not worked with Mole stub types before.  If there isn't a complete solution, an article\blog will also help.  I will be reading some of the posts on your blog as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RamiA I will append my answer with demo code.  I have some demos in the Moles section of my blog: http://TheCurlyBrace.blogspot.com/p/testing-with-microsoft-pex-moles.html

Comment: Thank you, Mike.  I could not really find some sample code that I could really use for my scenario.  I've updated my question with a sample sln with projects that illustrate the issue I am having.  Any detailed advice, more specific to the projects in the sln?